# Pandas Grouped Bar Chart

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plotly, bar-chart

I have a pandas data frame ***df*** that looks like this:

```
    Timestamp           ProductID.       OrderCount

  6/29/21 10:00       50100100200100       8
  6/29/21 10:00       50100100200101       7
  6/29/21 11:00       50100100200102       5
  6/29/21 11:00       50100100200105       8
  6/29/21 11:00       50100100200101      12
  6/29/21 12:00       50100100200109       4
  6/29/21 12:00       50100100200111       5
```

The timestamp data type is datetime64[ns], ProductID and OrderCount are float64 and int64 respectively.

I want to plot a bar chart where in the X-axis the ***ProductIDs*** will be grouped by the ***Timestamp*** and the height of the bars will be the ***OrderCount*** value.

So far I tried this:

```
  import pandas as pd
  from datetime import datetime
  import plotly.express as px
  import plotly.graph_objects as go
  import plotly.io as pio

  barchart = px.bar( 
       data_frame = df,
       x = "Timestamp",
       y = "OrderCount",
       orientation = "v",
       barmode = 'group',
  )  

  pio.show(barchart)
```

but this stacks up the OrderCount values and would print 15 for Timestamp==6/29/21 10:00 instead of plotting 8 and 7 as individual bars. A pandas newbie here, so help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grouping target for the X axis is the time series and ProductID. so you need to specify ProductID. for the color. ID is interpreted as a numerical value and a color bar is displayed, so you need to convert ID to a string in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

barchart = px.bar(
    data_frame = df,
    x = "Timestamp",
    y = "OrderCount",  
    color="ProductID.",
    orientation = "v",
    barmode = 'group',
)  

pio.show(barchart)
```

[image]

Comment: You can find the official reference [here](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#customize-bar-charts-with-plotly-express). Also, if my answer was helpful to you, there is a check button to check and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative:

```
df.pivot(*df).plot(kind='bar')
```

##### OUTPUT:

[image]